# Required environment variables for JDK 17

Tags: java, windows, java-17

I am trying to install java to my Windows 11 machine but when I try run
`java -version` in the command prompt, I get `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

In my computer's System variables I have a `PATH` variable with a link to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin`. I have looked at Oracle's installation instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-371F38CC-248F-49EC-BB9C-C37FC89E52A0) but it seems like it should be plug and play so to speak.

Are there additional environmental variables that I am missing or possibly I am pointing the path variable to the wrong location?

Comment: There is nothing else.  `PATH` should be all you need to make `java -version` work.  So check that your update to `PATH` is correct.  What happens when you run `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -version` ?

Comment: Did you close and reopen your terminal after the installation? Also, many tools rely on `JAVA_HOME` being set, but that's not needed here. And to be somewhat pedantic, Java doesn't require _any_ environment variables to be set. Setting the `PATH` is a convenience, and it's _other tools_ that may rely on `JAVA_HOME`. Some APIs in Java may use certain environment variables _if they are set_ (using default values if they aren't), but that will be documented for each individual API.

Comment: You seem to confuse environment variables needed for Java to execute with environments variables needed for your command line to find the Java executable. It seems that you want the later but the subject points to the former.

Answer (score 0):

After closing and reopening the command promt works.